# brew linkapps for homebrew casks (automatically create symlink to /Applications folder)

Tags: sublimetext2, homebrew, sublimetext, homebrew-cask

I am using homebrew and homebrew cask to manage my installations on my Mac with OS 10.10.5.

After installing an app using "brew cask install", no symlink in the /Applications folder shows up.

For apps installed via "brew install", a symlink to /Applications can be created by running the command "brew linkapps" – is there something similar for homebrew casks?

In this particular case, some features of the LatexTools package for Sublime Text 2 did not work (open pdf viewer automatically and jump to line in pdf) as LatexTools expects the pdf reader used to be located in, e.g. /Applications/Skim.app. Manually creating a symlink from the cask install location to /Applications via "ln -s" solved the problem.

Comment: Have you checked `~/Applications` as well? Most packages go to user's applications folder not the system's one.

Comment: They are indeed linked to `~/Applications`, the fact that the finder side bar entry "Applications" in Yosemite means `/Applications` added to my confusion here.

The issue was hence Sublime Text's LatexTools package's expectation of the install location of the skim pdf reader, which can be worked around by editing the packages' jumpToPDF.py file or by creating a symlink to /Applications as described above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `brew cask linkapps` and casks are linked to ~/Applications rather than /Applications, as noted above. However, this will supposedly change to brew-cask moving app bundles to /Applications rather than linking. (see https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/13201)